# node js calling functions

Tags: node.js

I am writing a big program (in size) using node js/Express.

I have multiple  app.post functions and all.
so, most of them need to do validation on coming  Request and send a response.

So, I am created a function called Validate();
if the validation fails I will send the response to telling " please try again with information where validation Failed".

so, I created

```
function validate() { ...}
```

in the

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
...

validate();
}
```

All the required parameters in req I am writing to a DB so I can access any where so that is not the problem now.
Issue is :
How do I send the "res"  object.
write now in validate if I try to call res. it will complain it is not defined.

so how to resolve this.

2) I tried to write the response of validate() in DB.
and after that I tried to call the res: that is :

```
app.post('/',function(req,res){
...

validate();

res ..
}
```

As node is asyc this function validate response is not used by the res.

has any one come across issue like this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should pass them as arguments:

```
function validate(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

```
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    validate(req, res);

    // ...
});
```

You can also define it as a custom middleware, calling a 3rd argument, `next`, when the request is deemed valid and pass it to [`app.post` as another `callback`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB):

```
function validate(req, res, next) {
    var isValid = ...;

    if (isValid) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.send("please try again");
    }
}
```

```
app.post('/', validate, function (req, res) {
    // validation has already passed by this point...
});
```

[Error handling](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling) in Express may also be useful with `next(err)`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. also In function declaration we mention the datatype. dont we need to mention the data type here

Comment: @TheLearner Nope. JavaScript variables are dynamic, so you just have to name them -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions. Though, if you're using another ECMAScript variant, such as TypeScript, then you might need to specify the types.